# In Button element, formaction='**.php' doesn't work

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am making the Ajax programming. That is, First Html starts and second, php receives the html signal , and finally xml contents are displayed.

I made html code and php code. But button formaction attribute in php code doesn't work. 
php code as like below

```
   if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q) || stristr($u->item(0)-

    >childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q))
  {
  if ($hint=="")
    {
    $hint="<button type='submit' name='code' value='" . 
    $u->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
    "' formaction='search.php'>" . 
    $u->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
    "</button>" . 
   "<a href='" . 
    $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
    "' target='_blank'>" .
    $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
    }
  else
    {
    $hint=$hint . "<br /><button type='submit' name='code' value='" . 
    $u->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
    "' formaction='search.php'>" . 
    $u->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
    "</button>" . 
   "<a href='" . 
    $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
    "' target='_blank'>" .
    $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
    }
  }
```

And in ajax,  result picture is below. 
[image]

But, when i click the button, no action happens.
What's wrong with me?

Comment: can you provide the html code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

`formaction='search.php'`

to

```
onclick='javascript:location.href=\'search.php\'';
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

want to submit form try this

```
    $hint= "<form action='search.php' methos='post' >"
    ."<button type='submit' name='code' value='" . 
    $u->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
    "' >" . 
    $u->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
    "</button>" . 
   "<a href='" . 
    $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
    "' target='_blank'>" .
    $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>".
    "</from>";
```

Comment: Doing `location.href` will not submit the form. It will redirect to the page search.php

Comment: then you must add a form tag if you want to submit not redirect

Comment: Really really, i appreciate your kind programming.

Answer (score 1):

Should be and also you need to apply action for `<form>` tag not for button action

```
action='search.php'
```

instead of

```
formaction='search.php'
```

You can add your code inside the `form` tag, give the `action='search.php'` into that, so it looks like

```
$hint= "<form action='search.php' methos='post' >";
$hint .=your code here 
  ....
$hint .='</form>';
```